# django, gunicorn, grpc: "Failed to pick subchannel" if run django grpc client with gunicorn

Tags: python, django, grpc

I am a beginner in the Django framework. I wrote an application consist of 2 microservices. One as a Django Rest Server and the other as a Django GRPC Server. the rest request translated to GRPC requests in the first server and sent to the second for the process.

```
      ------>|-----------|------->|-----------|
             |rest server|        |grpc server|
             |           |        |           |
      <------|-----------|<-------|-----------|
```

when I ran the first server with `python manage.py runserver ip:port` the application works properly. but when I ran the first server with `gunicorn myapp.wsgi --workers=1 --bind=ip:port`, a grpc request from the rest server randomly counter an error:

```
{"created":"@1593330482.005402565","description":"Failed to pick 
subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3981,"refer
enced_errors":[{"created":"@1593330482.005396918","description":"failed to connect to all 
addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_l
ine":394,"grpc_status":14}]}
```

**the interesting thing is the grpc request was received by grpc server and it sent back the response.**

wsgi.py:

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0):

`gunicorn` uses fork to spawns child processes. You can find out more about why this can be problematic, and how to enable fork support in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/fork_support.md.

In short, you can try to supply an env var `GRPC_ENABLE_FORK_SUPPORT=true`, or debug your traffic flow without gunicorn first.

Back to description, `Failed to pick subchannel` maybe happening before the RPC is sent. E.g., the name resolution took a while, or the backend wasn't up when the client starts. Please double check if the client-side missed the message.

If the problem persists, can you file an issue to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues?

Comment: I think I find the problem. in view.py for each request, I create a grpc channel. a channel take a time to connect to the server. I think if I send grpc request while the channel is not connected to the server, this error will happen. the code is under development. I will change the view.py to reuse grpc channel. after that, if the error persists I will use your suggestion and I will inform you about the result. thanks.

Comment: That's the second scenario I mentioned. You can explicitly block until the channel is ready, please see https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.channel_ready_future